# How to check if a string has a character in it in coldfusion

Tags: html, coldfusion

```
<td><input type="text" MAXLENGTH="5" <cfif isdefined ("saverecord1") and isdefined("form.startnum") and form.startnum neq ''>value="#form.startnum#" <cfelse>value=""</cfif> onkeyup="toupper(this)"  name="startnum" id="startnum"></td>

<td><input  MAXLENGTH="5"type="text" <cfif isdefined ("saverecord1") and isdefined("form.endnum") and form.endnum neq ''>value="#form.endnum#" <cfelse>value=""</cfif>   onkeyup="toupper(this)" name="endnum" id="endnum"></td> 

<cfset x = #REFind('[^a-z]', '#form.startnum#')# >                      

<cfset x = "#form.startnum#"> 
<cfif Len(Trim(x)) GT 0> 
    <cfset x = RemoveChars(x,1,1)> 
</cfif> 

<cfset y = "#form.ENDNUM#"> 

<cfif Len(Trim(y)) GT 0> 
    <cfset y = RemoveChars(y,1,1)> 
</cfif>     
<cfif y gt x>               
    <cfset total = y - x>   
<cfelse>
    <script>
    alert('Starting key number has to be greater than the ending key number! Please enter again');
    </script>   
</cfif>
```

I have 2 text boxes, in which the user can enter alphanumeric key numbers like M1000 and also numeric key numbers like 1000. I am able to handle the alphanumeric key numebers while generating autoincrementing key numbers.

But for numeric key entries like 1000 the above is failing as I am removing chars which do not exist and the entry is not being accepted. Please advice if refind() is the function I can use to find if there is any character in my string entry. thanks

Comment: What is your goal in plain english? Ensure the numeric part of `form.startNum` ie `1000` does not exceed `form.endNum`? Not related to your issue, but there is no need for any of those `#` signs, except the ones inside the `<input>` tags. Also, you could simplify the code by setting default `form` values with `cfparam`, then removing the `isDefined` statements.

Answer (score 1):

ReFind is a suitable function, but you are overwriting variable x before you use it.  Here you assign a value to x.

```
<cfset x = #REFind('[^a-z]', '#form.startnum#')# >
```

Then you assign another value to x

```
<cfset x = "#form.startnum#">
```

Then you use the variable:

```
<cfif Len(Trim(x)) GT 0>
```

That cfif is the same as

```
<cfif Len(Trim(form.startnum)) GT 0>
```

But you probably wanted this:

```
<cfif REFind('[^a-z]', '#form.startnum#') GT 0>
```